# I have at least 4 python interpreters on my PC, now what?

Tags: software-installation, python, ide, canopy

My ubuntu is 14.10, and I have upgraded it from 12.10 I think.

I just realized there are at least 3 python interpreters on my machine.

For a mooc, I have installed a fourth one, Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6, in my home directory. This is now the default.

```
python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:36:10)

/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 

/usr/bin/python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17)

/usr/bin/python3.3
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16)
```

Are all of them really needed? Should I uninstall python3.3?  What does ubuntu itself need?

Before I create a more complex environment by downloading packages and libraries, I better clean up a little as much as possible?

(I'm just asking because now with python 3 there are virtual environments. Maybe some big programs bring their own python interpreter. Before I start looking really thoroughly maybe some can explain to me what should be done these days. I know that a simpler variant of question has been asked here before in 2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.10 comes with Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4.2 so you should keep them.

Python 3.3.2+ isn't in the official software repositories and no program from there needs it. But you may have programs from other sources which depend on it.

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3.3` indicates that it belongs to a package `python3.3-minimal`. Do you know what this is for?

Answer (score 1):

`python3.3-minimal` contains the interpreter and some essential modules. It can be used in the boot process for some basic tasks. See `/usr/share/doc/python3.3-minimal/README.Debian` for a list of the modules contained in this package.

Yet as Florian Diesch explains Python 3.3.2+ is unofficial and not a necessity unless you have programs dependent on that listed by `/usr/share/doc/python3.3-minimal/README.Debian`